# How Do I use C# deserialization with a hierarchichal class structure

Tags: c#, class, serialization, hierarchy

I'm trying to deserialize some xml files into some classes which have been simplified to the following:

```
[XmlRoot("person")]
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Toy Toy { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ActionMan : Toy
{
    [XmlElement("guns")]
    public string Guns;
}

[Serializable]

public class Doll : Toy
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public  String Name;
}

[XmlInclude(typeof(Doll))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ActionMan))]
public class Toy
{
}

[TestFixture]
public class ToyTest
{
    [Test]
    public void testHierarchy()
    {
        String filePath = @"test\brother.xml";
        String sisfilePath = @"test\sister.xml";
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
        Person brother = (Person)serializer.Deserialize(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open));
        Person sister = (Person)serializer.Deserialize(new FileStream(sisfilePath, FileMode.Open));

        Assert.IsNotNull(brother);
        Assert.IsNotNull(sister);
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ActionMan),brother.Toy);
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Doll),sister.Toy);
    }
}
```

I want to use the c# Serialisation (I know I can use my own deserialiser) and I think I'm perhaps simply missing a particular tag that I don't know about (and I'm sure I've got superfluous tags).

here is one fo the xml files:

```
<person>
  <doll>
    <name>Jill</name>
  </doll>
</person>
```

the error I get is "Expected: assignable from " on the third assert

Comment: create an xsd for you schema and then generate the serializer code with xsd.exe

Comment: Can you modify the source code of the classes??

Comment: can modify anything apart from the XML. I wanted to use lightweight, standard and most importantly non-generated code if possible. if I absolutely have to use a generated serializer then fine, but I think there may be a simpler way that I'm missing.

Comment: Can you please check what data is loaded using debuger?

Answer (score 1):

Class person should contain a "doll" attribute instead of a "Toy" attribute, I mean the name. The XML node must have the same name as the attribute name -casing matters.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to serialize your structure (person, who has ActionMan as Toy) i get

> ```
> <person>
>   <Toy xsi:type="ActionMan" />
> </person>
> ```

I guess this is how you can handle inheritance of your types.
But I guess you cant change your already serialised XML.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done, is designed the class structure the way I want, fill in some basic data and then serialize it. Then examine how it serializes and adjust the Xml attributes. If your `Toy` class has only a few derivatives, then you can de-serialize them seperately with a action-man field and a doll field that might be null or not.

Alternatively to go from an Xml file to a c# class I use the `xsd.exe` tool to generate a `.xsd` file with `xsd mydata.xml` and then from that a c# class file with `xsd /c /l:cs mydata.xsd`. Then I examine the class data to get clues as to how to define my class and what attributes to use.

link to [xsd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) tool from Microsoft.

Comment: Nice paraphrasing of somebody else's answers.

Comment: @tou - a) First I +1 the other answer, b) I reported from my experiences, even if it identical to someone else's experience, and c) I added a new idea using the `xsd` too. What exactly is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
public class Person 
{

    public Toy toy
    {
        get
        {
            return (doll == null) ? (Toy)actionMan : (Toy)doll;
        }

    }


    public Doll doll;
    public ActionMan actionMan;
}


public class Toy 
{

}


public class Doll : Toy
{
    public String name;

}


public class ActionMan : Toy
{
    public String guns;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Person brother = new Person();
        ActionMan am = new ActionMan();
        am.guns = "Laser Beam";
        brother.actionMan = am;

        Person sister = new Person();
        Doll d = new Doll();
        d.name = "Jill";
        sister.doll = d;

        Serialize(brother, "brother.xml");
        Serialize(sister, "sister.xml");

        Person b = Deserialize("brother.xml");
        Person s = Deserialize("sister.xml");

        Console.WriteLine(((ActionMan)b.toy).guns);
        Console.WriteLine(((Doll)s.toy).name);
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static Person Deserialize(String filename)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
        return (Person)serializer.Deserialize(new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open));

    }

    public static void Serialize(Person p, String filename){
        Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
        s.Serialize(stream, p);
        stream.Close();

    }
```

You can expand from here. Remember that, in the attribute names, casing matters. The serialization output I got is

brother.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <actionMan>
    <guns>Laser Beam</guns>
  </actionMan>
</Person>
```

sister.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <doll>
    <name>Jill</name>
  </doll>
</Person>
```

The output is

```
Laser Beam
Jill
```

Comment: Both Doll and ActionMan classes inherit from Toy class. That's why assigning an instance of either one to the toy property in person works. The trick is the get method for toy property and the fact that the class Person contains a variable of each type --Doll and ActionMan.